# Less extend in media query not workling

Tags: css, class, less, extend, helper

my less extend is not working and i dont know why here are some snippets from my files!

Here from the **global.less:**

```
// Global Modifier
.is--rounded { .border-radius(); }

.is--block { display: block !important; }
.is--inline { display: inline !important; }
.is--inline-block { display: inline-block !important; }
.is--hidden { display: none !important; }
.is--invisible { visibility: hidden !important; }
```

And this from the **header.less** **works**

```
.header-gray {
    .shop--navigation {
        &:extend(.is--hidden);
    }
}
```

this from the **same header.less but didn't work**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .header-gray {
        .shop--navigation {
            &:extend(.is--block);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a syntax error ? or wheres the problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375305/less-css-extend-and-media-queries.

Answer (score 0):

From LESS documentation: "Extend written inside a media declaration should match only selectors inside the same media declaration"

Because your second example is wrapped in a media query, the .is--block declaration needs to match

Comment: Do I have to put all the classes like .is--block in every viewport ?

Comment: @Artij For this use-case it's more efficient to use mixins instead of extend. Extending "one property classes" does no actually give any benefits (especially if it's applied to a long selector name ruleset).